# Замеры с помощью cProfile в определенный промежуток

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот

в определенный промежуток времени, бот начинает лагать, и именно в определенный промежуток времени нужно вывести график времени работы функций cProfile, я находил аналоги такие как pyflame которые нужно атачить к процессу python, и можно делать запись 60 секунд каждые 10 мс к примеру, но с ним так и не получилось взаимодействовать тк как у меня arm64 архитектура. Я пробовал делать что то такое: но он не показывает мне именно нужный тайлампс(

```
def run(self):
    """Run the application."""
    with cProfile.Profile() as profile:

        logger.info(f"Total plugins: {len(self._plugins)}")
        logger.info("Starting...")

        if platform.lower().startswith("win"):
            asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

        # Set up the signal handlers
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.stop)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.stop)

        self._loop.create_task(self._main_loop_wrapper())
        self._loop.run_forever()

    results = pstats.Stats(profile)
    results.sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.TIME)
    results.print_stats()
    results.dump_stats("results.prof")
    logger.info("Stopped...")
    os._exit(0)
```

Comment: У объекта Profile есть методы enable()/disable() которые включают/останавливают запись. Можно проверять текущее время в каждой call-back функции или включать запись по команде в чате, раз уж это бот.